# How to run a bash script source from another bash script and invoke the corresponding functions. via crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron

- After I opened the terminal, I typed this command:

```
moabdelaziz@pop-os:\~$ crontab -r
```

- And scheduled the task:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/moabdelaziz/Backups/backup.sh >> /home/moabdelaziz/output.txt
```

- backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

TargetDir=/home/mohamed/Date
TargetBackup=/home/mohamed/Backup
EncryptionKey="PASS"
days=12

source ../backup_restore_lib.sh

validate_backup_params ${TargetDir} ${TargetBackup} ${EncryptionKey} ${days}
backup ${TargetDir} ${TargetBackup}
```

- backup_restore_lib.sh contains those functions

```
validate_backup_params {...}
Encryption {...}
Decryption {...}
remote_server {...}
backup {...}
validate_restore_params {...}
restore {...}
```

**Unfortunately, it does not work :(.**

**Can anyone point me to anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: The path `../backup_restore_lib.sh` will not generally be resolved based on the directory the script is in, but wherever working directory the cron daemon happened to use when it ran that job. Either use a full path, or use something like the process in ["How do I get the directory where a Bash script is located from within the script itself?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-do-i-get-the-directory-where-a-bash-script-is-located-from-within-the-script) to get the script's directory and resolve based on that. BTW, add `2>&1` to the cron entry to see errors in the log.

Comment: When you run a command from `cron`, the working directory will be the user's home directory. So you can use a path relative to that. Or just use the absolute path, as @GordonDavisson recommends.

Comment: Is `bash_script.sh` supposed to be `backup.sh`?

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Probably there is an error that `backup_restore_lib.sh` or `backup`won't be found. In any case, I suggest either an absolute path there, or do a `cd` in your script so that you end up in the directory you want the script run in. Also, you invoke `backup` without specifying an absolute path, but you never set the variable `PATH` in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, crontab scripts are executed in the home directory of the user. That means that your

```
source ../backup_restore_lib.sh
```

will look for a file `/home/backup_restore_lib.sh` to source.

It is better to put in the absolute path to the file that you want to source.